# ionic 6 Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I using ionic 6 to build my project. Now I'm using `BackgroundGeoLocation` to track users location. So I added capacitor and android then I followed `https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation`. In the docs it says we have to use it in app.ts so I used this in my app.component.ts but when I add this to contructor `constructor(private backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocation) { }` it throws `Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent in app component ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?)` How can I solve this? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide your imports on the app.component.ts file?

Comment: I think here the problem you added a plugin of cordova in capacitor app so items in constructor are not being detected by capacitor so its reading it as o ject object

Comment: Bart I'm importing constructor(private backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocation) { } only

Comment: Mostafa - No, I didn't add cordova plugin.